# Add New Query Strings to Existing URL in C# and Redirect to it

Tags: c#, html, .net, url

Can anybody help me with the c# code to add two query strings to an existing URL. URL typically looks like this below. When the URL is created in c# to redirect to it as well. Any help much appreciated.

```
http://localhost/somesite/index.php?Filename=somefile.txt&Filepath=E:\myfolder
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to build up url would be
option A: (string concat)

```
string param1 = "Filename=somefile.txt";
    string param2 = @"Filepath=E:\myfolder";
    Uri YourURL = new Uri($"http://localhost/somesite/index.php?{param1}&{param2}");
    Console.WriteLine(YourURL);
```

Option b: (URIBuilder)

```
UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
    uriBuilder.Scheme = "http";
    uriBuilder.Host = "localhost";
    uriBuilder.Path = "somesite/index.php";
    //uriBuilder.Port = 80;
    
    var q = new Dictionary<string,string>();
    q.Add("Filename","somefile.txt");
    q.Add("Filepath","E:\\myfolder");
    uriBuilder.Query = string.Join("&", q.Select(s => $"{s.Key}={s.Value}").ToList());
    uriBuilder.ToString().Dump();
```

to redirect. not sure what are you using for UI. the question is very blur.
but to redirect try this:

```
Response.Redirect(YourURL);
```

otherwise, please rewrite your question with better explanation

Comment: I was going to explore Option B. How do you retrieve the URL to variable from the option B code? and format the URL it so it will work with Response.Direct(). I simply want to update the new URL with query strings in the address bar of the browser.

Comment: uriBuilder.ToString() -will contain your url . so in controller return would be :: return Response.Redirect(uriBuilder.ToString());

Comment: Yes I modified as such uriBuilder.ToString(); Uri uri = uriBuilder.Uri; and to launch new URL Process.Start(uri.ToString());. Thank very much for your help Power Mouse

Comment: @user1234 If the answer helped you out, you can accept it for others to see.

Comment: Yes the answer was correct. I don't have enough point to upvote.